# how to pass data in cookie from one web application to other

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, redirect, cookies

I have two web application which are deployed in the different Application server. I am redirecting from one web application to another. I am setting some information in the Cookie object in web application 1 so that it is available in web application 2. I am using repose.sendRedirect() to send the request and Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies() to get cookie information but I am not able to get.
Please help me to solve this.

Comment: use of query-string will solve your problem.

Comment: Can you not pass the required info as request parameters?

Comment: Are those two applications running under different host names/ports? Then you can forget about cookies.

Answer (score 2):

cookies are domain specific so if your application are on two different domains you need to use another way like request parameters.